# Fetch() is not actually fetching data

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I've just started looking at Fetch API and I'm having some trouble actually getting it to work. Being new to it, my first assumption is I'm doing something incorrectly.

My first attempt was with a key-less API with Random User, which worked wonderfully:

```
fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/").then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error))
```

Then, I went on to a keyed API with Wunderground Weather, which didn't go so well:

```
fetch("http://api.wunderground.com/api/{API-KEY}/conditions/q/CA/San_Francisco.json").then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error))
```

Before you ask, I changed the "{API-KEY}" in the URL string with an actual API key. But for some reason, this API call isn't returning anything.

The API URL is copy/pasted directly from the Wunderground API documentation, [here](https://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=index&MR=1), as well as returns JSON successfully if pasted into Chrome's address bar.

[Here](https://codepen.io/HuntingHawk/pen/eyvVjg?editors=1011) is the codepen.io (sans API-KEY) that I'm using.

Comment: May test the url first if it works?

Comment: You need to do a jsonp request. I don't know fetch-api but you should find the way to do it. EDIT: i just find it: https://github.com/camsong/fetch-jsonp It would probably help.

Comment: Try using `https://` for the wunderground url.

Comment: @CodyG. Success! Write it as an answer so I can mark it as solved

Comment: Glad it worked for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `https://` for the wunderground url will prevent the browser from blocking mixed content.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content?utm_source=mozilla&utm_medium=firefox-console-errors&utm_campaign=default